# Kalman smoother in python

Tags: python, smoothing, kalman-filter

My data

```
1    14.7
2    14.58
3    14.82
4    14.59
5    14.67
...  ...
150  13.76
```

I already draw graph and upper/lower envelope line.
Next, I want to apply Kalman smoother for u/l envelope line.
Is there proper example about Kalman smoother??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my implementation of kernel filter, works fine on my data. This code was written based on https://www.kalmanfilter.net/kalman1d.html I hope this helps.

```
def kalmanfilter(x,p,z,r):
    # p - estimate unceratininty 
    # r - measurement unceratininty ( σ2 )  
    # z - Measured System State

    # Kalman gain calculation
    K =  p/(p+r)
    # estimate current state
    x1 = x + K*(z-x)
    # update current estimate uncertainity
    p1 = (1-K)*p

    return (x1,p1)
```

Comment: Uncertainty is variance in this case, since it's univariate

Comment: Which value does input x, p, z, r at my data format? 1,2,3....=x/14.7,14.58,14.82...=y
How can I find uncertainty? variance?

Comment: @Gal_tab I would suggest you to go through the attached link or any good written tutorial to understand the parameters for your data.

Comment: thx for your answer

Comment: If the answer serves your purpose can you please upvote it? @Gal_tab